# Как создать сервер на C# к которому смогут подключиться удаленные пользователи?

Tags: c#, winforms, клиент-сервер, tcp-ip, tcp

Очень долго пытаюсь создать сервер-клиент приложение через сокеты и Tcp протокол. Запускаю на своем компе сервер и клиентов, отправка сообщений и ответ от сервера работают корректно, но если клиент запускает кто-то другой то вылетает исключение, что превышено время ожидания и сервер не дал ответа. Как быть?
Ниже прикладываю код сервера и клиента.

`Сервер`

```
        string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
        IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(hostName);
        IPAddress[] ipAdresses = ipEntry.AddressList;

        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = 
             new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAdresses[0].ToString()), 2017);

        Socket sListener = 
             new Socket(IPAddress.Parse(ipAdresses[0].ToString()).AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
            sListener.Listen(10);

            while (true)
            {

                updateLog("Waiting for connection on [" + ipEndPoint + "]");

                Socket handler = sListener.Accept();
                updateLog("New user join the channel. [" + handler.LocalEndPoint + "]");

                string data = null;

                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);

                data += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);

                updateLog("Client[" + handler.LocalEndPoint + "]: " + data);

                // Отправка ответа клиенту.
                string reply = "Thanks for your query. We got it!";
                byte[] replyMSG = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reply);
                handler.Send(replyMSG);

                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();
            }
```

`Клиент`

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        IPAddress serverIp = IPAddress.Parse("Тут IP компьютера");

        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverIp, port);
        Socket sender = new Socket(serverIp.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        sender.Connect(ipEndPoint);
        byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msgTB.Text);
        int bytesSend = sender.Send(msg);
        int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);

        logTB.AppendText("Server: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));

        sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        sender.Close();
```

Comment: убедитесь что сервер настроен на получение пакетов через внешний адрес. Убедитесь что к серверу есть доступ из вне и корректно проброшены все необходимые порты через NAT при его наличии. Если локально все работает, то скорее всего проблемы именно сетевые.

Comment: Посмотри https://habrahabr.ru/post/323096/  там аналог AppDomain. Если хочешь аналог WCF то нужно заменить основной класс на свой и добавить общую сериализацию https://habrahabr.ru/post/323096/#comment_10107584

Comment: Ну и посмотри  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630653/tcp-ip-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0/634019#634019

Comment: если сервер расчитан на запись информации в базу и брать из басы, советую почитать про технологию asp.net, очень хорошие статьи есть на ресурсе metanit.com

Answer (score 1):

Вот примерно как должен сервер выглядеть...

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
            TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
            int counter = 0;

            serverSocket.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "Server Started"); 

            counter = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                counter += 1;
                clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "Client No:" + Convert.ToString(counter) + " started!");
                handleClinet client = new handleClinet();
                client.startClient(clientSocket, Convert.ToString(counter));
            }

            clientSocket.Close();
            serverSocket.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    //Class to handle each client request separatly
    public class handleClinet
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket;
        string clNo;
        public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, string clineNo)
        {
            this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
            this.clNo = clineNo;
            Thread ctThread = new Thread(doChat);
            ctThread.Start();
        }
        private void doChat()
        {
            int requestCount = 0;
            byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
            string dataFromClient = null;
            Byte[] sendBytes = null;
            string serverResponse = null;
            string rCount = null;
            requestCount = 0;

            while ((true))
            {
                try
                {
                    requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                    NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                    networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                    dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                    dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                    Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "From client-" + clNo + dataFromClient);

                    rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);
                    serverResponse = "Server to clinet(" + clNo + ") " + rCount;
                    sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                    networkStream.Flush();
                    Console.WriteLine(" >> " + serverResponse);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" >> " + ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

А вот возможная реализация клиента...

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
        NetworkStream serverStream; 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            msg("Client Started");
            clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
            label1.Text = "Client Socket Program - Server Connected ...";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Message from Client$");
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();

            byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
            serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
            msg("Data from Server : " + returndata);
        }

        public void msg(string mesg)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + mesg;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для реализации Вашей задачи посоветую обратиться к SOA, а именно к технологии WCF (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx).

Это передовая технология от Microsoft, которая скрывает от разработчика большую часть мишуры, связанной с RPC, а так же предоставляет беспрецедентную гибкость и масштабируемость.

Очень полезные видеоуроки по WCF найдете здесь 
https://itvdn.com/ru/video/wcf-essential